# Trouble with infinite summation involving $\sin$ function

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series

How can I proceed for this:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\bigg(\frac{\sin{(an+b)}}{an+b}\bigg)^2}$$

I know the answer is $\frac{\pi}{a}$, but how? I think it could be related to the Shannon sampling theorem, but any alternative solution would help as well.

Comment: Maybe the Poisson summation formula would help?

Comment: The Poisson summation formula is definitely the way to go, since the Fourier transform of $\text{sinc}(x)^2$ is the tent function, but the outcome is not $\frac{\pi}{a}$, especially if $a$ is negative or $b\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.